# Seek UWP version of Dennis' solution on Download financial data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP App in Windows Store which download historical data from Yahoo Finance. I would like to use Dennis' solution in my App. I have hard time to make that solution working for UWP, especially the part of cookie and crumb. Code sample is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. Here is what I have learned: In .NET.core, in addition to use Async methods to replace their counterpart, the cookie is retrieved from HttpWebResponse.Headers. Once cookie is resolved, all rest are the same as that provided by Dennis' solution.